# What CPU is good for single-threaded performance?

Tags: performance, 64-bit, cpu, x86

I have an app, which is single-threaded.  The source code is not available.  The people who managed it before me didn't really understand the whole "single-threaded" business and bought a ridiculously expensive 24-core box.  Of course, the performance didn't improve.

I am looking to increase performance. I've read that having a lot of cores actually decreases the performance of a single core.

So which CPUs are really good for single-threaded performance? Cost is no object.  The chip should be x86 and x64 compatible.

Comment: The App may be single threaded, but is it using anything like a SQL database which may benefit from the additional cores? If you explain more about what the app is doing we may be able to help more.

Comment: Also cost is always a object. If it really "is no object" then go pay a few 100 million to intel and have them make a one off chip for your box (I bet they would do it too for somewhere in the 100-500 million range) that is as fast as possible.

Comment: can you benefit from multiple instances of this app? could you run benchmarks against a simple consumer level system instead?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It does not use anything external other than a file.  It truly is single-threaded.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Looking at chips available out on the market, my employer can easily afford to buy pretty much any chip.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Unfortunately, the design of the app is not conducive to splitting up.  Believe me, it's the first thing I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMD's Turbo Core technology will rebalance cores when some of them become idle, giving the remaining busy cores a small speed boost.

Comment: And so will [Intel's Turbo Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Boost).

Comment: @Bob: The article says that IDA is what does the same thing. Turbo Core doesn't require OS support though.

Comment: Sadly, you will not find any AMD processors which can beat a top 10 list of Intel single threaded processors.

Comment: This is just one of the many benchmarks which tell the sordid story:http://www.cpubenchmark.net/singleThread.html . If you really need the highest single threaded perfomance get an enthusiast Intel chip and OC it to 5Ghz or so. If OC is not supported by management, then get a regular Xeon.